# Get Value from ASPxComboBox get value

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have combobox with 2 values, ID and Name. I need to get ID from selected item, and I don't know how.

```
ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue(ID);
```

Not working.

Comment: @DenysWessels it's Combobox, and Devexpress one.

Comment: have a look at **http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEditBase_GetValuetopic**

Comment: Please post your combo box code. It would be much simpler to find solution.

Comment: There isnt code. I just binded data from table, which have ID (int) and Name (varchar). I need to work with this ID which is selected from dropdown (set some value to selected value from combobox).

Comment: Ok. Where is the problem? Why ASPxComboBox.Value property doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have to use this ID (int) which is selected, and I don't know how to access it.

Comment: What do you get when you try with ASPxComboBox.Value? Value should contain ID if you set [ASPxComboBox.ValueField](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueFieldtopic) and [ASPxComboBox.ValueType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueTypetopic) properly.

Comment: I eventually solved it.
ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue("ID") works!
Thank you Filip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ASPxComboBox1.TextField = "Name"; //This is the displayMember   
ASPxComboBox1.ValueField = "ID";  //This is the valueMember
ASPxComboBox1.ValueType = typeof(String);
ASPxComboBox1.DataSource = DataTableWithIDandNameColumns;
ASPxComboBox1.DataBind();

String theID = Convert.ToString(ASPxComboBox1.Value);//The column in the datasource that is specified by the ValueField property.
   OR:
String theID = Convert.ToString(ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue("ID"));//Any column name in the datasource.
   Also:
String theName = Convert.ToString(ASPxComboBox1.SelectedItem.GetValue("Name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASPxComboBox.Value](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_Valuetopic) property.

Answer (score 0):

A combobox can only have one value per item and this is retrieved in your case by:

```
ASPxComboBox1.Value
```

See here in the [documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_Valuetopic).

Since the value returned will be of type `object`, you will need to cast this to the type originally set, e.g. `String`. Then you will be able to work with it.

Comment: It can have many if you bind data from table. I binded table with two rows.

Comment: No, the item can only have one value. The control can have multiple items and each item can only have one object set against its Value property. You may have bound a table to the Value property of the item but the item still only has one Value property.

Comment: Great. Any idea how to chose which column is value? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to cast the Value property to the type you originally set - I have updated my answer to describe.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem, when the ASPxComboBox's SelectedItem / SelectedIndex is incorrect, occurs when the ASPxComboBox's ValueType http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxComboBox_ValueTypetopic property is specified incorrectly.

Ensure that the ValueType is set, corresponding to the "Data Type Mappings (ADO.NET)" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx table.